# how to declare delegate method in specfic type in swift?

Tags: swift

A property with no specific type or protocol implementation. When calling methods on delegate, anything goes - the compiler will trust you if it can see that a method exists somewhere and the runtime will check if you were lying

I want like this way in swift

```
@property (nonatomin,strong)id delegate;
```

not like a protocol implementation

```
@property (nonatomin,strong)id <protocol> delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can define protocol and delegate in swift:

You can define protocol anywhere you can. Example:

```
protocol DemoProtocol{

    func doSomething(str: String){
    //Do Something when delegate fires
    }
}
```

Here is how you can define delegate in any of the class from which you need to call the delegate:

```
//Protocol Delegate
var delegate:DemoProtocol?
```

How to call delegate?

Inside any of the class:

```
delegate.doSomething("Delegate Called")
```

After that, you need to implement `protocol` to any of the class:

```
class Demo: DemoProtocol, UIViewController{

    //Here you will implement protocol method:

    func doSomething(str: String){
     //Do Something when delegate fires
    }
}
```

Comment: As `delegate` can be `nil` it's supposed to be called always with optional chaining `delegate?.doSomething("Delegate Called")`

Comment: hi i don''t need a protocol, i will use any of method from my delegate cls . is there any way for this ?

Comment: Of course not! How can you call other method class anywhere using delegate? Better use `NSNotificationCenter`